# Can R interpret a SIGINT/SIGTERM and execute a process as a result?

Tags: r, sigint, sigterm

Is there anyway to capture a SIGINT or SIGTERM from the shell in R so that I can try to execute some graceful exit code?

So far, I haven't found anything in my search.

Comment: There is *interrupt* handler in `tryCatch`, see [this working example](https://github.com/jangorecki/logR/blob/03af286b6dfa4246c545e39e385345933f4a7b4b/R/logR.R#L44). I'm not aware of *SIGTERM* handling.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since you asked and in the meantime someone solved this in a package:

https://github.com/atheriel/sigterm

From the README:

> **sigterm** is an extremely simple package that provides a way to implement just these kinds of operations in response to SIGTERM: when the package is loaded, it will install a signal handler that prevents R from immediately exiting. Users can then periodically check whether a SIGTERM signal has been received and respond appropriately.