# How do I check if a command used for pipe() failed?

Tags: r, io, pipe, signals

Say, I have written a compressor function of the form:

```
compress <- function(text, file){
    c <- paste0("gzip -c > ",shQuote(file))
    p <- pipe(c, open = "wb")
    on.exit(close(p))
    writeLines(text, p)
}
```

Now I can compress strings like this:

```
compress("Hello World", "test.gz")
system("zcat test.gz")
## Hello World
```

However, how can I check that the programm `gzip` called by `pipe()` succeeds?

E.g.

```
compress("Hello World", "nonexistent-dir/test.gz")
## sh: nonexistent-dir/test.gz: No such file or directory
```

results in an error message printed on STDERR but I have no way in creating an R error. The program just continues without saving my text.

I know that I can just check for the existence of the target file in this example. But there are many possible errors, like end of disk space, the program was not found, some library is missing, the program was found [but the ELF interpreter was not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378301/linux-executable-fails-with-file-not-found-even-though-the-file-is-there-and-i) etc. I just can't think of any way to test for all possible errors.

I searched the help page `?pipe`, but could find no hint.

As a UNIX-specific approach, I tried to trap the SIGPIPE signal, but could not find a way to do this. Stack Overflow questions regarding this topic remain unanswered as of now [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823237/can-r-interpret-a-sigint-sigterm-and-execute-a-process-as-a-result) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936141/how-to-let-rscript-behave-similar-to-other-linux-programs-by-not-generating-erro)

**How do I check the exit code or premature termination of a program called with `pipe()`?**

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution using `pipe()`, but the package **processx** has a solution. I first create the external process as a background process, obtain a connection to it and write to that connection.

Before I start to write, I check if the process is running. After all is written, I can check the exit code of the program.

```
library(processx)
p <- process$new("pigz","-c",stdin="|", stdout = "/tmp/test.gz")
if(!p$is_alive()) stop("Subprocess ended prematurely")
con <- p$get_input_connection()
# Write output
conn_write(con, "Hello World")
close(con)
p$wait()
if(p$get_exit_status() != 0) stop("Subprocess failed")
system("zcat /tmp/test.gz")
```